# Implement refresh token in APIsix and keycloak, validate token against realm, and verify tenant ID in JWT plugin against request-referrer value

Tags: oauth-2.0, lua, refresh-token, lua-scripting-library

I have tried this [text](https://www.elasticpath.com/blog/oauth2-authentication-with-lua) reference but didn't work properly.
I am expecting that if login is unsuccessful, put retry mechanism. If second time, same thing happens, show unauthorized error. And if backend returns 302 - redirect to login or logout page. capture at api six level and respond in such a way that angular needs to send home page with jwt token again. (again validation would happen automatically). If angular app can detect such url change, that would be perfect.

If the login attempt fails, I anticipate a retry mechanism. If the same item occurs a second time, display an unauthorised error. Redirect to the login or logout page if the backend gives a 302 error. capture at the api level six and react in a way that forces Angular to resend the home page and jwt token. (Again, automatic validation would take place). It would be ideal if the angular app could recognise such url changes.